# Help with Tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

**What I need**

[image]

**My attempts**

[image: Image created by aboves tikz-code]

I'm not good at tikz at all, so could You help me draw this horrible thing, please.

I used *mathcha.io* as an editor(bad idea) [code](https://www.mathcha.io/editor/xqpQPfpVIxmF8Jfd1K5gt2Z86jpCrgKem9HrJpJ4L)

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
    
    \tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
    %uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300
    
    %Shape: Circle [id:dp6029210067809341] 
    \draw   (213.97,130.41) .. controls (213.97,116) and (225.66,104.31) .. (240.07,104.31) .. controls (254.49,104.31) and (266.17,116) .. (266.17,130.41) .. controls (266.17,144.83) and (254.49,156.51) .. (240.07,156.51) .. controls (225.66,156.51) and (213.97,144.83) .. (213.97,130.41) -- cycle ;
    %Curve Lines [id:da6648802025288789] 
    \draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 27; green, 42; blue, 182 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] [dash pattern={on 3.75pt off 1.5pt}]  (218.67,144.96) .. controls (251.87,145.36) and (252.67,139.76) .. (266.27,127.36) ;
    %Curve Lines [id:da8544308129087157] 
    \draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 36; green, 39; blue, 213 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] [dash pattern={on 3.75pt off 1.5pt}]  (214.87,124.96) .. controls (228.67,146.16) and (248.67,146.16) .. (260.27,146.96) ;
    %Straight Lines [id:da07874343757931257] 
    \draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 231; green, 27; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (240.2,145.44) -- (240.04,172.07) ;
    \draw [shift={(240.02,175.07)}, rotate = 270.35] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 231; green, 27; blue, 27 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
    %Straight Lines [id:da20393748210971685] 
    \draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 31; green, 21; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] [dash pattern={on 3.75pt off 1.5pt}]  (240.02,42.96) -- (240.02,79.69) ;
    %Straight Lines [id:da025853040544491446] 
    \draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 238; green, 32; blue, 32 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (240.2,142.42) -- (240.02,63.24) ;
    \draw [shift={(240.02,60.24)}, rotate = 89.87] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 238; green, 32; blue, 32 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
    %Straight Lines [id:da6915957280858298] 
    \draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 238; green, 32; blue, 32 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (240.2,125.87) -- (240.12,84.78) ;
    \draw [shift={(240.11,81.78)}, rotate = 89.88] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 238; green, 32; blue, 32 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
    
    
    
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to draw that detailed rock with a texture in pure tikz?

Comment: Sorry, your code-link just shows a drawing program ... which is not even close to tikz. On the other hand, tikz isn't that difficult. Kindly check out the short and after that the longer manual at: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf . Looking forward to your first tikz-code, here.

Comment: @antshar, no no just circle instead of rock as You can see

Comment: @MS-SPO my link  shows a drawing program and let You see the tikz code too, You just do not now where to click, I supose)

Comment: You have the image you drew. What would you like to add to it? The water, labels and the rock at the top?

Comment: @M.AlJumaily "The water, labels and the rock at the top?" Yes

Comment: As a physicist your tikz drawing still has flaws: it doesn't show the center of gravity, at least not correctly. The blue lines on the rock in the "foto" were created by hanging the object at two sides and marking the lines of a plummet. Their intersection yield the center of gravity. Your drawn sphere is puzzling in this view. // Abstraction would be into a dot of mass m with zero diameter. You could draw a sphere around it, as the relevant feature here seems to be volume V, creating some buoyancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt where you can easily scale the output (there are minor adjustments to worry about afterwards):

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,transform shape]
    %Outer background with the text at the bottom
    \draw [draw=red, fill=orange,fill opacity=0.10] (-2.5, -1) 
    node[below, pos=0, yshift=-8pt, text=black, opacity=1] {Pmc.11} 
    rectangle (2.5, 6.5) ;
    %Blue background with the three lines
    \fill [cyan, fill opacity=0.33] (-2, 0) rectangle (2, 4.5);
    %Three-border outline
    \draw[black, very thick] (-2, 4.75) -- (-2, 0) -- (2, 0) -- (2, 4.75);
    %The circle and two blue lines
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0, 2)}]
        \clip (0, 0) circle (1cm);
        \draw[fill=white, very thick] (0, 0) circle (1cm);
        \draw[thick, dashed, blue] (-1,0.25) to[out=-40,in=-90] (1,-0.25);
        \draw[thick, dashed, blue] (-1,-0.5) to[out=-5,in=-30] (1,0.5);
    \end{scope}
    %The three arrows with labels
    \node[label={[label distance=-20pt,xshift=10pt]below:$m\vec{g}$}] at (0, 0) (a) {};
    \node[label={[label distance=-8pt,xshift=10pt]below:$\vec{F}_A$}] at (0, 3.5) (b) {};
    \node[label={[label distance=-10pt,xshift=-10pt]below:$\vec{T}$}] at (0, 4) (c) {};
    \node[] at (0, 5) (d) {};%top line
    \draw[-Stealth, red] (a) -- (b);
    \draw[Stealth-Stealth, red] (a) -- (c);
    \draw[blue,dashed, shorten <= -6pt] (c) -- (d);
    %The top hatched rectangle along with its background and
    % the bold black line at the bottom
    \draw[black,line width=2mm] (-1,5) -- (1,5);%bold line
    \fill [lightgray] (-1,5) rectangle (1,6);%background
    \fill [pattern={Lines[angle=0,distance=2pt]}, pattern color=black,inner sep=0pt] 
    (-1,5) rectangle (1,6);%hatched lines
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very cool, thank You.